# Magento 2.1.6 - Component Update update/index.php server error

Tags: magento2, permissions

When trying to install a component in magento 2.1.6 every check passes, backup completes and when i go to press the install button i get directed straight to a 500 internal server error page. I have checked all permissions as per magentos documentation and everything seems fine. The URL that throws is it: update/index.php

Answer (score 0):

My mistake. I changed update/index.php to 644 permission.